# Connect oracle database to another database

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect oracle db to oracle db
I tried to create database link on toad like this.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK boston
  CONNECT TO admin IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' 
  USING 'host=192.168.1.65 dbname=sales';
```

It is created with no error but not working properly.

I need working "create database link" format with using ip address and service name.

```
Oracle Host to connect ip: 192.168.1.65 
oracle version: 10g 
Service name: xe 
Table name: sales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the proper connection string as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK boston
    CONNECT TO admin IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.65)(PORT=1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales))
            )';
```

The best practice is to add the connection string in the **tnsnames.ora**

```
SALES =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.65)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = sales)
    )
)
```

then use this **tns alias** in the `DB link` as following:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK boston
    CONNECT TO admin IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
    USING 'SALES';
```

Cheers!!